# What does keras do after definition of loss function?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, theano

I constructed a network, dense(10)-softmax-crossentropy, in both of theano and keras(theano backend).
I dump out the computational graphs respectively.
On theano version(Fig. 1, this computational graph was what I thought.
But on keras version(Fig. 2), it seems to be added computations after the definition of loss(crossentropy). why?

Please teach those who understand what you are doing ..

[Fig.1 Theano version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDc8V.jpg)

[Fig.2 Keras(backend is Theano) version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCoXu.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Keras, after loss computation, sample weights and loss weights are applied to the loss. See these lines in the script [training.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L461-L464).

- Sample weight:

  ```
      score_array = K.mean(score_array, axis=list(range(weight_ndim, ndim)))
      score_array *= weights
      score_array /= K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx()))
  return K.mean(score_array)
  ```
- Loss weight:

  ```
  if total_loss is None:
      total_loss = loss_weight * output_loss
  ```

It's straightforward to map these lines back to the computational graph. For example, the following block computes `K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx()))`:

[image]

- The first node computes `K.not_equal(weights, 0)`
- The second node is `K.cast(..., K.floatx())`
- All other nodes are about `K.mean(...)`

  - The left branch computes the batch size (call `shape`, and get dimension `0` from it)
  - The right branch computes tensor sum
  - Divide the output of the right branch by the output of the left branch
- The final output of this block is the scalar `K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx()))`